# curl problem --insecure -k

Tags: curl

I have a problem with `curl` and the domain `dhl.com`. I have this error:

```
curl -k "https://www.dhl.com"
curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
```

What causes this error and how may I work around it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443 if there is something useful for you. Some proxy setting ? Would be good if you gave more details about your setup.

Comment: Same here actually, with and without `-k`

Comment: i really don't understand ... it's work fine with Postman App... but not in Terminal Shell :-(